# How can i make for play a sound in an accurate time of the chronometer?

Tags: android, time, audio

I am working in an app with chronometer that when an user press the button a sound playing, and when the time at 10:00 other sound playing, but i can't play the last one, Here the code:

```
btIniciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (click){
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + tempoQuandoParado);
        chronometer.start();

        Toast.makeText(GerenciaPartida.this, "The match begin!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        MediaPlayer musica = MediaPlayer.create(GerenciaPartida.this, R.raw.apito);
        musica.start();


        }


***Here i want play another sound at 10:00, when the time's over***




        }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use timer.

```
    Timer myTimer = new Timer();
```

When you start chronometer start the timer like in example below. 600000 - is 10 minutes in milliseconds.

```
    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //play sound
        }
    }, 600000);
```

Comment: I'm not achieving,  What the other parameter that i need use before the time?

Comment: Just copy paste code and start playing sound where are comments. Other parameter is new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //play sound
        }
    }

Comment: Hello my friend, i'm having the error: The method scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask, long, long) in the type timer is not applicable for the arguments (new TimerTask(){}, int)